# MySQL date time comparison seems incorrect

Tags: mysql, datetime

Following are the queries and the outputs

```
mysql> select q.id id,CONVERT_TZ( q.lastUpdatedAt,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) lastUpdatedAt from Question q inner join QuestionInformation qi on q.id=qi.question_id;

+-----+---------------------+
| id  | lastUpdatedAt       |
+-----+---------------------+
| 206 | 2014-08-10 06:49:17 |
| 207 | 2014-08-10 06:49:59 |
| 208 | 2014-08-10 06:50:47 |
| 209 | 2014-08-10 06:51:04 |
| 210 | 2014-08-10 06:51:42 |
| 211 | 2014-08-10 06:52:10 |
| 212 | 2014-08-10 16:09:13 |
| 213 | 2014-08-10 16:12:04 |
| 214 | 2014-08-10 16:22:53 |
| 215 | 2014-08-10 16:23:44 |
| 216 | 2014-08-10 16:25:55 |
| 217 | 2014-08-10 16:46:39 |
+-----+---------------------+

12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select q.id id,CONVERT_TZ( q.lastUpdatedAt,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) lastUpdatedAt from Question q inner join QuestionInformation qi on q.id=qi.question_id where   lastUpdatedAt > '2014-08-10 11:10:07';

+-----+---------------------+
| id  | lastUpdatedAt       |
+-----+---------------------+
| 217 | 2014-08-10 16:46:39 |
+-----+---------------------+

1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

But there is more than one row where the last updated time is greater than 2014-08-10 11:10:07. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is Question.id null for some records?

Comment: No. And even if it were, I don't think it will explain the difference between the output to the two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you think that you are getting `lastUpdatedAt` *after* the time zone conversion, but you are not.  In the query:

```
select q.id id, CONVERT_TZ(q.lastUpdatedAt,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) as lastUpdatedAt
from Question q inner join
     QuestionInformation qi
     on q.id=qi.question_id
where lastUpdatedAt > '2014-08-10 11:10:07';
```

The `where` clause is really:

```
where q.lastUpdatedAt > '2014-08-10 11:10:07';
```

To fix this, you can repeat the expression in the `where` clause:

```
select q.id id,
       CONVERT_TZ(q.lastUpdatedAt,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) as lastUpdatedAtTZ
from Question q inner join
     QuestionInformation qi
     on q.id=qi.question_id
where  CONVERT_TZ(q.lastUpdatedAt,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) > '2014-08-10 11:10:07';
```

Or give it a different alias and use a `having` clause:

```
select q.id id,
       CONVERT_TZ(q.lastUpdatedAt,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone) as lastUpdatedAtTZ
from Question q inner join
     QuestionInformation qi
     on q.id=qi.question_id
having lastUpdatedAtTZ > '2014-08-10 11:10:07';
```

The latter is a MySQL extension.  In other databases, you would use a subquery or CTE.